# replacing the values of a column based on some conditions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

input:

```
item   loc   month    year    qty_name      qty_value
a       x     8        2020    chocolate      10
a       x     8        2020    gum            15
a       x     8        2020    maggi          11
a       x     8        2020    colgate        18
b       y     8        2020    chocolate      20
b       y     8        2020    gum            30
b       y     8        2020    maggi          40
b       y     8        2020    colgate        9
c       s     8        2020    gum            15
c       s     8        2020    maggi          11
c       s     8        2020    colgate        18
```

expected output:

```
item   loc   month    year    qty_name      qty_value
a       x     8        2020    chocolate      10
a       x     8        2020    gum            15
a       x     8        2020    maggi          0
a       x     8        2020    colgate        0
b       y     8        2020    chocolate      20
b       y     8        2020    gum            30
b       y     8        2020    maggi          0
b       y     8        2020    colgate        0
c       s     8        2020    gum            15
c       s     8        2020    maggi          11
c       s     8        2020    colgate        18
```

description:

For an `item`, `loc`, `month`, `year` combination:

if `chocolate>0`, then except for chocolate and gum all other values will become 0(this is happening in itam a and b)

and if chocolate is not present, then values will remain as it is(this is happing in item=c, and loc=s)

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. Only tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using. Don't forget, you need to include your attempts as well, and explain why the code you have isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql version 8 or above you can use window functions. Here `COUNT() OVER()` counts chocolates in another column and makes it value same for all rows. Then upper query you can check results.

```
SELECT ITEM,
       LOC,
       MONTH,
       YEAR,
       QTY_NAME,
       CASE
          WHEN QTY_NAME NOT IN ('chocolate', 'gum') AND CNT > 0 THEN 0
          ELSE QTY_NAME
       END
          QTY_NAME
  FROM (  SELECT ITEM,
                 LOC,
                 MONTH,
                 YEAR,
                 QTY_NAME,
                 QTY_VALUE,
                 COUNT (CASE WHEN QTY_NAME = 'chocolate' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
                    OVER ()
                    CNT
            FROM TEST_TABLE
        GROUP BY ITEM,
                 LOC,
                 MONTH,
                 YEAR,
                 QTY_NAME,
                 QTY_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below assumes that there are not multiple records for 'chocolate' within a given combination of `item`, `loc`, `month`, `year`. As is the case for your sample data. With that assumption, there is no need for aggregation over each combination.

Simply update all records to a quantity of zero that are not 'chocolate' or 'gum' where a record exists for the same combination with a quantity for 'chocolate' that is higher than 0.

**Sample data**

```
create table quantities
(
  item nvarchar(1),
  loc nvarchar(1),
  month int,
  year int,
  qty_name nvarchar(10),
  qty_value int
);

insert into quantities (item, loc, month, year, qty_name, qty_value) values
('a', 'x', 8, 2020, 'chocolate', 10),
('a', 'x', 8, 2020, 'gum'      , 15),
('a', 'x', 8, 2020, 'maggi'    , 11),
('a', 'x', 8, 2020, 'colgate'  , 18),
('b', 'y', 8, 2020, 'chocolate', 20),
('b', 'y', 8, 2020, 'gum'      , 30),
('b', 'y', 8, 2020, 'maggi'    , 40),
('b', 'y', 8, 2020, 'colgate'  , 9),
('c', 's', 8, 2020, 'gum'      , 15),
('c', 's', 8, 2020, 'maggi'    , 11),
('c', 's', 8, 2020, 'colgate'  , 18);
```

**Solution**

```
update quantities q
join quantities q2
  on  q2.item = q.item
  and q2.loc = q.loc
  and q2.month = q.month
  and q2.year = q.year
  and q2.qty_name = 'chocolate'
  and q2.qty_value > 0
set q.qty_value = 0
where q.qty_name not in ('chocolate', 'gum');
```

**Result**

```
select * from quantities;

item    loc month   year    qty_name    qty_value
------- --- ------- ------- ----------- ----------
a       x   8       2020    chocolate   10
a       x   8       2020    gum         15
a       x   8       2020    maggi       0
a       x   8       2020    colgate     0
b       y   8       2020    chocolate   20
b       y   8       2020    gum         30
b       y   8       2020    maggi       0
b       y   8       2020    colgate     0
c       s   8       2020    gum         15
c       s   8       2020    maggi       11
c       s   8       2020    colgate     18
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71d564/1)

*EDIT: This is a MySql solution because the question was previously tagged with it. I do not have an Apache Spark SQL engine on hand to validate this solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pyspark way.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.filter("qty_name = 'chocolate' and qty_value > 0").select('item', 'loc', 'month', 'year').withColumn('marker', f.lit('Y'))

df.join(df2, ['item', 'loc', 'month', 'year'], 'left') \
  .withColumn('qty_value', f.when(f.expr("marker = 'Y' and qty_name not in ('chocolate', 'gum')"), 0).otherwise(f.col('qty_value'))) \
  .drop('marker').show(12, False)

+----+---+-----+----+---------+---------+
|item|loc|month|year|qty_name |qty_value|
+----+---+-----+----+---------+---------+
|a   |x  |8    |2020|chocolate|10       |
|a   |x  |8    |2020|gum      |15       |
|a   |x  |8    |2020|maggi    |0        |
|a   |x  |8    |2020|colgate  |0        |
|b   |y  |8    |2020|chocolate|20       |
|b   |y  |8    |2020|gum      |30       |
|b   |y  |8    |2020|maggi    |0        |
|b   |y  |8    |2020|colgate  |0        |
|c   |s  |8    |2020|gum      |15       |
|c   |s  |8    |2020|maggi    |11       |
|c   |s  |8    |2020|colgate  |18       |
+----+---+-----+----+---------+---------+
```